# $\sigma$-algebra defined by a function

Tags: measure-theory

It is easy to see that if $f:X\to Y$ is a function and $S_X$ is a $\sigma$-algebra over $X$ then $S_Y:=\{A\subseteq Y:f^{-1}(A)\in S_X\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra over $Y$.

Suppose now that $S_X=\sigma (C_X)$ for some $C_X$, this is, $S$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $C_X\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$.

Consider $C_Y=\{A\subseteq Y:f^{-1}(A)\in C_X\}$. Is it true that $S_Y=\sigma(C_Y)$?

Clearly $C_Y\subseteq S_Y$, so $\sigma(C_Y)\subseteq S_Y$. But in the other hand, I don't know how to see if it's true that $S_Y\subseteq\sigma(C_Y)$. What do you think? Could this be false?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can have $\sigma(C_Y) \subsetneq S_Y$: Let $Y$ a set containing at least two elements, $X = Y\times \mathbb{N}$, and $f$ the natural projection onto $Y$. Further, let $C_X$ be the family of finite subsets of $X$. Then $C_Y = \{\varnothing\}$, and $\sigma(C_Y)$ is the trivial $\sigma$-algebra, but $S_X$ is the countable/cocountable $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, and $S_Y$ is the countable/cocountable $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Not always. Try $X=Y=\{a,b\}$, $S_X=\{\varnothing,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$, $f(a)=f(b)=a$ and $C_X=\{\{a\}\}$.

Then $S_Y=\{\varnothing,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$ and $C_Y=\varnothing$ hence $\sigma(C_Y)=\{\varnothing,\{a,b\}\}$ is not $S_Y$.